# Catching errors on actor construction in Akka TestKit

Tags: akka.net

I am trying to learn unit testing with Akka.

I have a situation where one of my tests was throwing an exception on construction and was wondering what the best way to capture this and log or otherwise throw it would be. As it stands now I had to attach a debugger and see where it threw.

I thought that I could perhaps create another actor which does logging and, on error, have a message sent to it. Breakpoints I put in the ErrorActor were never hit though. It seems as though the RootActor failed and timed out before the message was sent / received.

Is there something I'm doing wrong here or am I fundamentally off base with this? What is the the recommended way to catch errors in unit tests?

Thanks very much

```
    [Fact]
        public void CreateRootActor()
        {
            // Arrange
            var props = Props.Create(() => new RootActor());
            Sys.ActorOf(Props.Create( () =>new TestErrorActor(TestLogger)), ActorPaths.ErrorActor.Name); // register my test actor
            
            // Act
            var actor = new TestActorRef<RootActor>(this.Sys, props);

            // Assert
            Assert.IsType<RootActor>(actor.UnderlyingActor);
        }



   public class RootActor : ReceiveActor
    {

         private ITenantRepository tenantRepository;

        public RootActor(ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope)
        {
            try
            {
                this.tenantRepository = lifetimeScope.Resolve<ITenantRepository>(); // this throws

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Context.ActorSelection(ErrorActor.Name).Tell(new TestErrorActor.RaiseError(e));
                throw;
            }
            ....
```

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by using Akka.Logger.Serilog and a try / catch in the RootActor. I deleted the ErrorActor.